# Playframework Custom CORSFilter implementation

Tags: java, scala, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I am trying to implement CORS Filter in Play framework 2.7.X where I want all the subdomains for allowedOrigin with something like this

allowedOrigin ="*.o1test.com"

I am have tried using implementing HttpFiltersComponents by passing these params. I am not getting the proper java or scala example to implement this. Any sample will help me.

Comment: You mean configuring the existing filter rather than implementing I guess? See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/CorsFilter

Comment: `.o1test.com` without the `*` should work

Comment: Can any give me the java code corresponding the custom cors implementation? I tried using following public class CorsFilterConfigiration implements HttpFiltersComponents

Comment: I don't understand. What is custom cors implementation? You want to implement your own? Why? And even then what is your issue?

Comment: Default cors filter I have to add the allowed origins one by one like "https://a.o1test.com", "https://b.o1test.com" but I do not want to do this. I would have wild card wildcardAllowedOriginMatchers like "*.o1test.com". Hope my usecase is clear.

Comment: As said above, remove the `*`